# react native textinput useState not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

react native textinput useState not working.

I thought textinput value and useState description value same.
But onSubmit description value is empty.

console.log('descriptiondescription >>>>>> ',description) is very well.

sorry my bad english
Help.. thank you!!

```
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('descriptiondescription >>>>>> ',description)
}, [description]);

const onSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('description >>> ', description)
    navigation.pop();
    const asset = res.assets[0];
    const extension = asset.fileName.split('.').pop();
    const reference = storage().ref(`/photo/${user.id}/${v4()}.${extension}`);

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await reference.putString(asset.base64, 'base64', {
            contentType: asset.type,
        });
    } else {
        await reference.putFile(asset.uri);
    }

    const photoURL = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    await createPost({user, photoURL, description});

    events.emit('refresh');
    
},[res, user, description, navigation]);

            <TextInput 
                style={styles.input}
                multiline={true}
                textAlignVertical="top"
                value={description}
                onChangeText={setDescription}
            />
```

Comment: 1. Try looking into the console to see if there are any errors.
2. Try exploring what signature `onChangeText` has, maybe it has some event object as parameter and thus can not set text value properly

Comment: onChangeText={(text) => { console.log('text:', text);      setDescription(text);  }}
    Is very well...
 What else should I check?

Comment: and this outputs correct value to console?

Comment: yes. The console displays the correct values.
However, onSubmit returns an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
```

useState sets description to "" so nothing. hence why you are being returned nothing when calling the variable description.

use setDescription to set the description to something or change what's inside the useState

```
const [description, setDescription] = useState('Change this');
```